# How can I merge two documents, get rid of duplicates and keep certain data?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, pipeline

I have the following data, which describes who is going to do what work.

Basically I want to replace the "workId" and "userId" with objects that contain all the data from their respective documents and retain the "when" data.

I am starting with this data:

```
{
  "schedule": {
    "WorkId": "4e51dc1069c27c015ede4e3e",
    "daily": [
      {
        "when": 1,
        "U_W": [
          {
            "workId": "3a60dc1069c27c015ede1111",
            "userId": "5f60c3b7f93d8e00a1cdf414"
          },
          {
            "workId": "3a60dc1069c27c015ede1122",
            "userId": "5f60c3b7f93d8e00a1cdf415"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the user table

```
  "userSchema": [
    {
      _id: "5f60c3b7f93d8e00a1cdf414",
      Name: "Bob"
    },
    {
      _id: "5f60c3b7f93d8e00a1cdf415",
      Name: "Joe"

    }
  ],
```

Here is the work table

```
  "workSchema": [
    {
      _id: "3a60dc1069c27c015ede1111",
      Name: "shovel"

    },
    {
      _id: "3a60dc1069c27c015ede1122",
      Name: "hammer"
    }
  ]
```

what I want to end up with is this

```
{
  "schedule": {
    "WorkId": "4e51dc1069c27c015ede4e3e",
    "daily": [
      {
        "when": 1,
        "U_W": [
          {
            "work": {
              "id": "3a60dc1069c27c015ede1111",
              "name": "shovel"
            },
            "user": {
              "id": "5f60c3b7f93d8e00a1cdf414",
              "name": "bob"
            }
          },
          {
            "work": {
              "id": "3a60dc1069c27c015ede1122",
              "name": "hammer"
            },
            "user": {
              "id": "5f60c3b7f93d8e00a1cdf415",
              "name": "joe"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my first attempt:
I have it joining the the two documents

How can I get rid of the duplicates ( bob:hammer and joe:shovel ) ?
and how do I include the "when" ?

Here is the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EUSxGsWEoE7) that provides the following :

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "user_info": {
      "Name": "Bob",
      "_id": "5f60c3b7f93d8e00a1cdf414"
    },
    "work_role": {
      "Name": "shovel",
      "_id": "3a60dc1069c27c015ede1111"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "user_info": {
      "Name": "Bob",
      "_id": "5f60c3b7f93d8e00a1cdf414"
    },
    "work_role": {
      "Name": "hammer",
      "_id": "3a60dc1069c27c015ede1122"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "user_info": {
      "Name": "Joe",
      "_id": "5f60c3b7f93d8e00a1cdf415"
    },
    "work_role": {
      "Name": "shovel",
      "_id": "3a60dc1069c27c015ede1111"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "user_info": {
      "Name": "Joe",
      "_id": "5f60c3b7f93d8e00a1cdf415"
    },
    "work_role": {
      "Name": "hammer",
      "_id": "3a60dc1069c27c015ede1122"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/3431869/vamsi-prabhala ... if you have some time... would you take a look at my question... I am having a little difficulty... thank you !

Comment: hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/2527905/dnoeth ... would you mind taking a look at this question if you have some time?  thank you !

Answer (score 0):

After beating my head against the wall for some time...
I found a pretty cool feature of mongo "references"

eg:

```
  REF_work: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'work' },
  REF_person: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'users' },
```

then when I call it from my get function I add a populate to the find

```
assignments.find(query).populate('daily.cp.REF_person').populate('daily.cp.REF_work');
```

I get exactly what I want:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "REF_person": {
      "Name": "Bob",
      "_id": "5f60c3b7f93d8e00a1cdf414"
    },
    "REF_work": {
      "Name": "shovel",
      "_id": "3a60dc1069c27c015ede1111"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "REF_person": {
      "Name": "Joe",
      "_id": "5f60c3b7f93d8e00a1cdf415"
    },
    "REF_work": {
      "Name": "hammer",
      "_id": "3a60dc1069c27c015ede1122"
    }
  }
]
```